# Как сохранить ответ с сервера, чтоб его можно было использовать в методе render()

Tags: reactjs, fetch

Имеется компонент React

```
export default class DepartmentInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            departmentList: ''
        };

        this.getDeparnmentList = this.getDeparnmentList.bind(this);
    }

    getDeparnmentList(url) {
        fetch(url, {method: 'GET'})
            .then((res) => {
                res.json().then((data) => {
                    this.selectItems = data;
                })
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.getDeparnmentList('/getDepartmentList');
    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.selectItems);
        return (
            <div className='DepartmentInput'>
                <select className='DepartmentInput__select'>

                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Как обработать ответ сервера, чтоб его значение в методе render не было undefined

Comment: Запишите его в state и используйте.

Comment: res.json()
  .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
          departmentList: data
      })
   })

Разве ето не вызовет метод рендер 2 раза?

Comment: Попробуйте и посмотрите :)

Comment: получаю 2 вывода в консоль: сначала undefined потом нужные данные

Comment: Перекиньте `fetch` в `componentDidMount`